# ListView reusing old images

Tags: android, nativescript

I created a plugin using [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) and it uses the [android.widget.ImageView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html) to load the cached image into.
The plugin works fine if using a Repeater but whenever i try using it with a ListView after scrolling past about the 7th item the ListView begins to reuse old images even if the image source is different

[image]

Comment: Could you provide the code of the adapter class you use for the ListView?

Comment: The [plugin](https://github.com/triniwiz/nativescript-image-cache-it)
My code [myList](https://gist.github.com/triniwiz/204c20cc03a5f0cd2e48c062e9434b77) ,

[myControl](https://gist.github.com/triniwiz/a0f4db3a25a5c109e070a800b672e719)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why is because list views reuse the entire fragment; so what happens is that your img being reused gets the old image shown unless you clear it.

I actually use Picasso myself; and this is my current picasso library.
So if you look in my code below, when I set the new .url, I clear the existing image. (I made a comment on the specific line) -- This way the image now show blank, and then picasso loads it from either memory, disk or a remote url (in my case a remote url) and it will assign the proper image.

```
"use strict";

var Img = require('ui/image').Image;
var application = require("application");

var PT = com.squareup.picasso.Target.extend("Target",{
    _owner: null,
    _url: null,
    onBitmapLoaded: function(bitmap, from) {
        // Since the actual image / target is cached; it is possible that the
        // target will not match so we don't replace the image already seen
        if (this._url !== this._owner._url) {
            return;
        }
        this._owner.src = bitmap;
    },
    onBitmapFailed: function(ed) {
        console.log("Failed File", this._url);
    },
    onPrepareLoad: function(ed) {

    }
});

Object.defineProperty(Img.prototype, "url", {
    get: function () {
        return this._url;
    },
    set: function(src) {
        if (src == null || src === "") {
            this._url = "";
            this.src = null;
            return;
        }
        var dest = src;
        this._url = dest;
        this.src = null; // -- THIS IS THE LINE TO CLEAR THE IMAGE
        try {
            var target = new PT();
            target._owner = this;
            target._url = dest;
            var x = com.squareup.picasso.Picasso.with(application.android.context).load(dest).into(target);
        } catch (e) {
            console.log("Exception",e);
        }
    },
    enumerable: true,
    configurable: true
});
```

Please note you only need to require this class once, then it attaches itself to the <Image> component and adds the new **.url** property; this allows me to use this in the Declarative XML in all the rest of the screens and when I need picasso, I just use the .url property to have picasso take over the loading of that image.

Comment: Thanks but i used `onImageSourcePropertyChanged(data: PropertyChangeData) {
    var image = <ImageCacheIt>data.object;
    if (!image.android) {
        return;
    }

    image._setNativeImage(data.newValue ? data.newValue.android : null);
}`

Comment: I'm not following what you are trying to say here.  Are you saying you figured out how to use the above to clear the image properly?   Or you are doing your code totally different?

Comment: I went about fixing my problem another way